# Timing chain replacement and the CVVT system

Tags: kia, camshaft

I have this KIA Cerato "Forte" 2010 with an G4FC DOHC 16V 1.6L MPI with a single CVVT on the intake side.

I'm changing the timing chain, tensor and the two sliders,  I thought it is a simple procedure but I've come cross [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuKrnIzU4Bs) which say you should unlock the VVT hub then install it and lock it back. is this really necessary ? what I think of it is the vvt hub will get the camshaft to the right position after the engine start despite the initial position relative to the sprocket during the alignment.

also as this hub has been tempered with before "opened" and I couldn't find a replacement part for it is it possible to just eliminate the CVVT by locking  the hub "could be soldered" at one position " which should be calculated " and does the injunction/ignition system depend on it or will it adopt to the eliminated hub ?

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you didn't remove the VVT actuator don't worry about it. The reason you reset the position is so that the timing isn't off. I'm unsure of the style of actuator your Kia uses but on Toyota's it's a vane style actuated by oil pressure. The only time the actuator should of moved is when oil pressure is flowing to it.

If you solder or weld the actuator together you'll set timing codes and more than likely the engine would lack power past a certain RPM. Don't have access to service information for the 1.6, but on the 2.0 with single or dual VVT they don't mention locking the actuator.

Comment: it is oil pressure actuated on this one also. it looks the same as on the Toyota with a VVT-I , for now the car starts normally with the hub locked (permanently fixed) but there's some noise from another parts